# Saving app state on iphone

Tags: iphone

I'm developing a word game for iphone. Now that IOS has multitasking, do I definitely have to save the game state when the game is interrupted?

Answer (score 2):

Your app can be unloaded by iOS whenever it decides to do so.  Low memory, the user forces the app to close, etc.

Yes, you should save your game state if you want to be able to reinstate it when the app launches from scratch.

Comment: I agree, I mainly work with Android that allow several apps running also and it is good practice to save the state as you go along

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into three20's persistance

http://three20.info/showcase/persistence